# file not found using curl and opendir

Tags: php, upload

the following script uses the kat.ph upload api to upload torrents; however i am getting an file not found error when using echo to figure out what was wrong, why is the file not being uploaded as I can see the file in my directory

```
<?php
$dhandle = opendir('.');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$length = ob_get_length(); 
$katphdata ['desc'] = 'torrentdescription';
$katphdata ['name'] = 'testingscript';
$katphdata ['category_name'] = '38';
$katphdata ['torrentFile'] = 'name.torrent';
$katphdata ['userhash'] = 'hash';
foreach ( $katphdata as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://kat.ph/torrents/upload/');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent", "Content-Length: $length"));
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_items);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
return $result;
var_dump($result);
//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);
//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);





?>
```

this is their form for the torrent upload

```
    <input type="file" class="primary inputfile" name="torrentFile" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="goodalertfield inlineblock">You can upload only <strong>*.torrent</strong> files</div>
<br />
```

Comment: maybe you should login first and then post...

Comment: ^ logged in already, either way i believe it users the userhash for auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, remove content-header and add referral agent and it works fine